# Substitution for jQuery live and on

Tags: jquery, bind, jquery-1.4

What is the correct way to get the same functionality of live(), and
on() in jQuery < 1.5.

Comment: Manually create listeners... But why would you do that?

Comment: delegate()............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[.delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**

```
 $( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is for jQuery version 1.7 and above.  If you have an older version, use this:

```
$("#SomeId").live("click",function(){
    //do stuff;
});
```

But you can use `live()` because you are using `jQuery<1.5`

Answer (score 0):

use `delegate` https://api.jquery.com/delegate/ works for jQuery 1.4.3+